# Replacing for loop with one liner for deleting dictionary

Tags: python

I wanted to ask if there any solution for *ommiting* this **for loop** with *one liner* or *anything*?

```
Data = [{"name": "Gill","age": "20", "id":"10001", "gender": "female"}, {"name": "Rakshit", "age": "22", "id":"10002"}]

new_Data = {"id":"10001"}

for i, x in enumerate(Data):
     if x['id'] == new_Data['id']:
          del Data[i]
```

Comment: deleting an element from an existing list isn't really possible with list comprehension (or that isn't what they're for)

Comment: Your current implementation is bugged. Don't modify a list (changing its size) while you iterate over it.

Comment: `Data[:] = [d for d in Data if d['id']==new_Data['id']]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use **list comprehension** to achieve this task of **filtering**:

```py
Data = [{"name": "Gill","age": "20", "id":"10001", "gender": "female"}, {"name": "Rakshit", "age": "22", "id":"10002"}]

new_Data = {"id":"10001"}

filtered_data = [data for data in Data if not data['id'] == new_data['id']]
```

Comment: The op isn't filtering, they're modifying an existing list

Comment: @Sayse you're technically correct (and that is the best form of correct), but this is the better way to do it.

Comment: Ok, but i want to update `Data` by deleting the dictionary with same `id` of `new_Data['id']`

Comment: Then say `data = [...]` instead of `filtered_data`

Comment: Technically it's possible to delete items from `Data` list using one-liner with generator. `all(Data.pop(-i - 1) for i, v in enumerate(reversed(Data)) if v["id"] == new_Data["id"])`. **Disclamer:** It's just proof-of-concept, do not use this.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I mean, you can do the same thing with a list comprehension, in *either* case, you shouldn't be using them for side-effects

Comment: @Sayse to be fair, the OP's solution is bugged. In this case, you could do something like `data[:] = [<list comprehesino>]` anyway, if you feel the need to actually modify the data

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Sure I saw the op's code as pseudo code to begin with before checking issues with it, normally when using `del` you're likely to do so because its a large list that you don't want to iterate over completely but sure if they're replacing the whole thing then list comprehensions could have been what they were really after

Comment: Yeah, ok. Thanks a lot for ur help

Answer (score -3):

If you're trying to remove items in-place you can do it with a comprehension, but it's a bit wonky:

```
>>> lx = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
>>> [lx.pop(i) for i in sorted((idx for idx, val in enumerate(lx) if val == 2), reverse=True)]
[2, 2, 2]
>>> lx
[1, 3]
```

The main thing to note here is you're getting the indexes that you want to delete, and then reversing the order you pop them off in. That way you don't disrupt your later indexes by popping off earlier ones.

If you're concerned about creating an unnecessary list, this is also possible with a generator:

```
>>> lx = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
>>> all(lx.pop(i) for i in sorted((idx for idx, val in enumerate(lx) if val == 2), reverse=True))
True
>>> lx
[1, 3]
```

Notably, though, there is little reason to go about it this way. The main reason for deleting a list in-place is conservation of memory. But in your case you've got dictionary as list items. Your original list is really just holding pointers to those values, and if you use a simple list comprehension to filter your original list, it too will have references to your dictionary items:

```
>>> ls = [{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}]
>>> lx = [i for i in ls if i.get("a", False)]
>>> lx
[{'a': 1}]
>>> ls[0]["a"] = 2
>>> ls
[{'a': 2}, {'b': 2}]
>>> lx
[{'a': 2}]
```

This demonstrates that a change in the original list is mirrored in your filtered list, even after the filter takes place. Thus, the memory you use in creating a new, filtered list is really just the size of the references - relatively small. It is no slower, really, since the memory allocation is O(n), equal to your iteration over the original list. So, while you *can* modify the original list in-place, there isn't a lot of reason to do so and some pitfalls you avoid (such as the one in your original post, where you could end up skipping items because you're deleting indexes front to back).

Comment: Don't even *suggest* this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is there a reason not to?

Comment: Yes. This is using a list-comprehension for side effects. it's bad for many reasons, the main one being style, but it also unnecessarily creates a list. If you *must* use a list comprehension to mutate an already existing list, you should use something like `data[:] = [x for x in data if condition]` so at least the list comprehension isn't being used for side-effects (again, very very bad). Note, your current implementation in particular is worst-case O(N**2), and at least O(N*logN), but this is trivially accomplished in linear time

Comment: ... or even `data[:] = (x for x in data if condition)`

Comment: There are perfectly valid reasons for doing this. *Especially* in the case of using `pop()`, such as you want to know what you're removing and do something with it.   If your objection is just 'it creates another list', then we can just use a generator. While it's not 'pythonic' a prohibition against side effects is a little silly without a better reason than 'there are side effects'.